# Angular 6: ng test library with IE (Polyfills)

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular6

I just migrated an angular library project to angular version 6 (which makes building libraries so much easier). I used `ng generate library` to create a sub-project in my angular project following [this guide](https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5). My main project is an app that I can use to see the library in action when developing.

Now I can run tests like `ng test my-library`. But I would like to test my library with the target environment, which is IE unfortunately. I configured the polyfills and now try to use `ng test my-library --browsers=IE`, but the polyfills seem to only be respected for the main app - my library will exit the tests quickly with an error that looks polyfills-related (Object does not support `fill` - roughly translated as my environment is german).

Is there any way to tell angular that I would like to run my library tests "polyfilled"? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this quite simply after all - I copied the **polyfills.ts** file into my subproject-folder and added an import into the library-specific **test.ts** file (this was automatically created when I generated the library project).

```
import './polyfills';
```

Answer (score 3):

It's also possible to add it to your **angular.json**:

```
…
"test": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
    "options": {
      "main": "projects/my-library/src/test.ts",
      "tsConfig": "projects/my-library/src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "karmaConfig": "projects/my-library/src/karma.conf.js",
      "polyfills": "projects/my-library/src/polyfills.ts"
    },
}
…
```

and to your **projects/my-library/src/tscofnig.spec.json**:

```
…
"files": [
  "test.ts",
  "polyfills.ts"
],
…
```

---

I would prefer adding it to the configuration files as this is the standard way and it's easier for new people joining the project as they are already familiar with it.